# Changing percentages (commission) in PayPal chained payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I'm currently developing a website in which users can sell their own product and we will take, as the marketplace holders, a percentage on each purchase.

My problem is: I want this percentage to drop down (from 10% to 5%), for users who will subscribe to our monthly fee subscription.
How can i set this feature with PayPal chained payments?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not something you would set with chained payments itself.  That's just something you'll have to calculate within your own application and then build your Pay request to PayPal accordingly.

So you'll need to track what percentage you should be charging based on your user profile data and/or code logic, and then calculate the pricing when you build the request.